# Opening a fragment with a button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need some help. I've done some extensive searching for the past 4 hours and I'm not sure if it's because I have errors in my code, or if I'm not doing something correctly. 
Basically, this is what's going on. I have my main activity 'homepage' which opens to a second activity with a navigation drawer. I assume that the navigation drawer is also an 'activity'. I am trying to open a fragment within that activity with the button, but I keep getting a fatal exception:

```
10-14 21:36:54.469      799-799/com.example.workstation.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workstation.app/com.example.workstation.app.navigation_drawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.workstation.app.navigationdrawer.onCreate(navigationdrawer.java:57)
```

Here is the code I am working with, this one is for the navigation_drawer activity (I believe):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.workstation.app.navigation_drawer_activity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cctr_ct"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_search"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:text="Search"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_favorites"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/favorites"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cctr_search"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cctr_ct_home"
        android:text="Favorite"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_recent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/recent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctr_search"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cctr_search"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cctr_search"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="Recent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_contactus"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/email"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cctr_recent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cctr_favorites"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cctr_favorites"
        android:text="Contact Us" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.workstation.cctrmobileapp.cctrct_search"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_ct_search"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the navigation drawer works fine, it's opening the fragment from the button I'm having trouble with. I get the error above. Here is the java code from the activity that comes with the navigation drawer:

```
package com.example.workstation.cctrmobileapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class cctr_clinical_trials extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, cctrct_search.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    Button cctrct_searchButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cctr_clinical_trials);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        cctrct_searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cctr_search);

        cctrct_searchButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                cctrct_search newFragment = new cctrct_search();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

/*        cctrct_searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager searchFragment = getSupportFragmentManager();

                searchFragment.beginTransaction()

                        .replace(R.id.container, cctrct_search.newInstance("test1", "test2"))

                        .commit();
            }

        });*/


    }
```

and for the heck of it, here is the xml for the fragment that I want to appear after I press the button:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.workstation.cctrmobileapp.cctrct_search">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_search_submit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctrct_p1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Only the submit button works"
        android:id="@+id/cctr_search_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phase III"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_p3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctrct_search_pnum"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phase II"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_p2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cctrct_p1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cctrct_p3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cctrct_search_keyword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cctrct_search_keyword"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phase I"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_p1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cctrct_search_pnum"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cctrct_p2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cctrct_search_pnum"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Keyword"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_search_keyword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cctrct_search_submit"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cctrct_search_submit"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Disease Site"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_search_dsite"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctr_search_logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Protocol Number"
        android:id="@+id/cctrct_search_pnum"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cctrct_search_keyword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I just figured I would add the rest of the code from my class:

```
 @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position) {
            case 0: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit(); break;
            case 1: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, cctrct_search.newInstance("test1", "test2"))
                    .commit(); break;
            case 2: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit(); break;
            case 3: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit(); break;
        }

    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.cctr_ct_home);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.cctr_ct_search);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.cctr_ct_saved);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.cctr_ct_recent);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cctr_clinical_trials, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cctr_clinical_trials, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((cctr_clinical_trials) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Here are similar questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811496/starting-fragment-from-button-in-another-fragment

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983738/button-open-a-fragment

Comment: Can you post your navigationdrawer.java code? It says the NullPointerException is occuring on line 57

Comment: That is actually the code above. I was trying to change some of the lines, but eventually, I realized there were too many.... so I just left the rest of them...

It's basically pointing to: **cctrct_searchButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `cctrct_searchButton` is **null** which means it is *not being found* in the **view**. *Is a Button with the id* `cctr_search` *present in the* `activity_cctr_clinical_trials` *layout xml file*?

Comment: the activity_cctr_clinical_trials.xml only contains the items required for the navigation drawer. Do I need to add a new fragment with "id = "cctr_search""? did I perchance place my fragment in the wrong xml? I have it in fragment_cctr_clinical_trials.xml file

Comment: Your cctr_clinical_trials inflated activity_cctr_clinical_trials. Which means it only has access to the views on that layout. Technically you can get access to buttons on fragments, but only after the fragments have been added. And fragments are not added immediately (unless you invoke executePendingTransactions). So the question is, where are these buttons you are trying to press?

Comment: sphanley, i'm not sure who you are talking to but your comment is very unproductive

Comment: The buttons are placed under fragment_cctr_clinical_trials.xml

should all these buttons be placed on activity_cctr_clinical_trials.xml?

Comment: I think based on how you have it setup, you should be accessing and adding your button listeners in the Fragments onCreateView method. Not the Activity's onCreate

Comment: well, I believe that my fragment and activity share the same onCreateView method. I'm starting to get confused by my code!

Comment: I have added the rest of my code from the java code

Comment: Thank you once again Mr. Spidy,

You are correct about using the method in the onCreateView method rather than onCreate

Comment: Activity's and Fragment's do not share lifecycle methods. They have similar ones that can overlap and somewhat interact with each other but definitely aren't shared.

Answer (score 0):

For future users, Mr. Spidy was 100% correct, the onClickListener should have been in the onCreateView and not in the onCreate section:

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cctr_clinical_trials, container, false);


            Button cctrct_searchButton;

            cctrct_searchButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cctr_search);

            cctrct_searchButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Fragment newFragment = new cctrct_search();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });

            return rootView;

        }
```

THANKS AGAIN MR. SPIDY